# opening pdf file in app

Tags: java, android, pdf

im making an app consist of some pdf file but i dont know how i can work with that
1- where i should copy my pdf files in resource ? (which folder?)
2- what code needed to open its ? (what codes need to write in onClick method ? )
3- what class and methods is usfull for this procedure ?

leave this below codes ( they are for body error ignoring )

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the PDF from a **webview** you can use the following code:

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView mWebView=new WebView(MyPdfViewActivity.this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+LinkTo);
    setContentView(mWebView);
  }
}
```

If you would like to open the PDF locally, you can an place it in either the res/raw folder or the assets folder(in the following example the assets folder is used). Then you need to place the file locally using the following code:

```
private void copyAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
    }
    for(String filename : files) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
          in = assetManager.open(filename);
          File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
          out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
          copyFile(in, out);
          in.close();
          in = null;
          out.flush();
          out.close();
          out = null;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
        }       
    }
}
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the following code to access the PDF, again assuming the user has a PDF viewer installed:

```
public class OpenPdf extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OpenPdfButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File("/sdcard/example.pdf");

                if (file.exists()) {
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    try {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } 
                    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(OpenPdf.this, 
                            "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you want to open it from your application you can try [this](https://code.google.com/p/apv/)